# How to setup Apache Iceberg access rights to allow users write to a table branch (or branches with prefix)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-iceberg, nessie

There is a table `my_table` in Apache Iceberg. I want to allow some groups of user to write to this table but only for branches that start with `analytic_` prefix. E.g. user can create `analytic_task_12345` branch and write data to it.

Is it possible with pure Apache Iceberg? Is it possible with Apache Spark and Nessie?

Comment: I dont think Iceberg provides authorization or access control features by itself. Rather, it relies on other services (Ranger+plugins for Hive, Impala, etc.) to secure the data.

Answer (score 0):

Nessie does have an Authorization framework that should allow this logic to be implemented.

High-level details can be found on this page: https://projectnessie.org/features/metadata_authorization/

The AuthZ rules are enforced on the Nessie Server side, so they apply to all engines, including Spark.